# ElectronJs: app.quit is crashing the application

Tags: electron

**Task**
Terminate the application when all the windows are closed or the Main Window is closed.

**Problem**
application crashing when the `app.quit()` is called.

**Code**

```
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    // if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    //     app.quit();
    // }

    app.quit();
});



mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null;
    app.quit();

});
```

**Log**

```
[901:0531/114426:FATAL:resource_dispatcher_host_impl.cc(658)] Check failed: ContainsKey(active_resource_contexts_, context). 
0   Electron Framework                  0x000000010bfa3903 _ZN4base8internal30DstRangeRelationToSrcRangeImplIilLNS0_21IntegerRepresentationE1ELS2_1ELNS0_26NumericRangeRepresentationE0EE5CheckEl + 389891
1   Electron Framework                  0x000000010bfb9ec9 _ZN4base8internal30DstRangeRelationToSrcRangeImplIilLNS0_21IntegerRepresentationE1ELS2_1ELNS0_26NumericRangeRepresentationE0EE5CheckEl + 481481
2   Electron Framework                  0x000000010c83b765 _ZN4base8internal30DstRangeRelationToSrcRangeImplIilLNS0_21IntegerRepresentationE1ELS2_1ELNS0_26NumericRangeRepresentationE0EE5CheckEl + 9400677
3   Electron Framework                  0x000000010c8ff0cc _ZN4base8internal30DstRangeRelationToSrcRangeImplIilLNS0_21IntegerRepresentationE1ELS2_1ELNS0_26NumericRangeRepresentationE0EE5CheckEl + 10201804
4   Electron Framework                  0x000000010bf15009 _ZN9brightray14BrowserContext15ResourceContextD2Ev + 9
5   Electron Framework                  0x000000010bf14f79 _ZN9brightray14BrowserContext15ResourceContextD1Ev + 9
6   Electron Framework                  0x000000010bf14f8e _ZN9brightray14BrowserContext15ResourceContextD1Ev + 30
7   Electron Framework                  0x000000010bf158cf _ZN4base12DeleteHelperIN9brightray14BrowserContext15ResourceContextEE8DoDeleteEPKv + 15
8   Electron Framework                  0x000000010bfa3e0b _ZN4base8internal30DstRangeRelationToSrcRangeImplIilLNS0_21IntegerRepresentationE1ELS2_1ELNS0_26NumericRangeRepresentationE0EE5CheckEl + 391179
9   Electron Framework                  0x000000010bfc2973 _ZN4base8internal30DstRangeRelationToSrcRangeImplIilLNS0_21IntegerRepresentationE1ELS2_1ELNS0_26NumericRangeRepresentationE0EE5CheckEl + 516979
10  Electron Framework                  0x000000010bfc2c4c _ZN4base8internal30DstRangeRelationToSrcRangeImplIilLNS0_21IntegerRepresentationE1ELS2_1ELNS0_26NumericRangeRepresentationE0EE5CheckEl + 517708
11  Electron Framework                  0x000000010bfc2e3b _ZN4base8internal30DstRangeRelationToSrcRangeImplIilLNS0_21IntegerRepresentationE1ELS2_1ELNS0_26NumericRangeRepresentationE0EE5CheckEl + 518203
12  Electron Framework                  0x000000010bf98a31 _ZN4base8internal30DstRangeRelationToSrcRangeImplIilLNS0_21IntegerRepresentationE1ELS2_1ELNS0_26NumericRangeRepresentationE0EE5CheckEl + 345137
13  Electron Framework                  0x000000010bfd57e3 _ZN4base8internal30DstRangeRelationToSrcRangeImplIilLNS0_21IntegerRepresentationE1ELS2_1ELNS0_26NumericRangeRepresentationE0EE5CheckEl + 594403
14  Electron Framework                  0x000000010bfc216d _ZN4base8internal30DstRangeRelationToSrcRangeImplIilLNS0_21IntegerRepresentationE1ELS2_1ELNS0_26NumericRangeRepresentationE0EE5CheckEl + 514925
15  Electron Framework                  0x000000010c6e7b38 _ZN4base8internal30DstRangeRelationToSrcRangeImplIilLNS0_21IntegerRepresentationE1ELS2_1ELNS0_26NumericRangeRepresentationE0EE5CheckEl + 8009016
16  Electron Framework                  0x000000010c6e7d0e _ZN4base8internal30DstRangeRelationToSrcRangeImplIilLNS0_21IntegerRepresentationE1ELS2_1ELNS0_26NumericRangeRepresentationE0EE5CheckEl + 8009486
17  Electron Framework                  0x000000010bff4758 _ZN4base8internal30DstRangeRelationToSrcRangeImplIilLNS0_21IntegerRepresentationE1ELS2_1ELNS0_26NumericRangeRepresentationE0EE5CheckEl + 721240
18  Electron Framework                  0x000000010bff0937 _ZN4base8internal30DstRangeRelationToSrcRangeImplIilLNS0_21IntegerRepresentationE1ELS2_1ELNS0_26NumericRangeRepresentationE0EE5CheckEl + 705335
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff8780405a _pthread_body + 131
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff87803fd7 _pthread_body + 0
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff878013ed thread_start + 13
```

[image]

Comment: My best guess is it's because you're calling `app.quit` twice technically. Why not just call it on either `all-windows-closed` or when the `mainWindow` is closed? What happens if you do just one?

Comment: @ccnokes many thanks. it worked :)

Comment: Great! I just added it as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `app.quit()` twice which is causing the crash. Only call it once in either the `all-windows-closed` event handler or `closed` event handler on the `mainWindow`.